# pass more than one array between activity using bundle

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

When I call activity, I want to pass array as extra so I used below code:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(getContext(), abc.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray(EXTRA_MESSAGE_LOCATION, new String[] { "vlaue1" });
activityIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(activityIntent);
```

But with this I can pass only one array at time.
Can I pass more than one array?

Answer (score 1):

```
bundle.putStringArray(EXTRA_MESSAGE_LOCATION, new String[] { "vlaue1" });
```

bundle is like an HashMap. Use a different key :

```
putStringArray(EXTRA_MESSAGE_LOCATION_2
```

for instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried that but that is not work for me. bundle.putStringArray(EXTRA_MESSAGE_LOCATION,
     new String[] { "value1","value5" });
   bundle.putStringArray(EXTRA_MESSAGE_PINTITLE,
     new String[] { "value2","value3" });

Comment: @Deer are you sure you are retriving both with the correct key?

Comment: ===Call with this===
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putStringArray(EXTRA_MESSAGE_LOCATION,
     new String[] { "value1","value2" });
   bundle.putStringArray(EXTRA_MESSAGE_PINTITLE,
     new String[] { "value3","value4" });
   activityIntent.putExtras(bundle);
   startActivity(activityIntent);

===retrive with this===
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
  strAryLocation = bundle
    .getStringArray(MembersAdapter.EXTRA_MESSAGE_LOCATION);
  strAryPinTitle = bundle
    .getStringArray(MembersAdapter.EXTRA_MESSAGE_PINTITLE);

Comment: what is EXTRA_MESSAGE_LOCATION and EXTRA_MESSAGE_PINTITLE value?

Comment: ===I declared them at class level===public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_LOCATION = "com.example.myapp.MESSAGE";
 public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_PINTITLE = "com.example.myapp.MESSAGE";

Comment: I like you. They are the same string... change it in com.example.myapp.MESSAGE_LOCATION and com.example.myapp.MESSAGE_PINTITLE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18475/discussion-between-deer-and-blackbelt)

Comment: Thanks blackbelt =com.example.myapp.MESSAGE_LOCATION and com.example.myapp.MESSAGE_PINTITLE= this solved my problem thanks a lot...!?!